# maincontroller.js mainmodel.js not loading in liferay from extjs 6?

Tags: deployment, liferay, liferay-6, extjs6

[image]

Here I am not able to add both of these files before this it was not adding main.js, so I added that in index.html

```html
   <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/examplecalculator/app/view/main/Main.js"/>
```

And now it is not loading other two files.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i am using liferay 6.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Required JavaScript or CSS Resource can be loaded with you portlet declarative inside liferay-portlet.xml

It should look like:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>YourPortletNeedingAJSresource</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/app/view/main/Main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
</portlet>
```

The path /app/view/main/Main.js was guessed according to your snipped. It should be adjusted according to your project structure.